# Ajax Call in sandbox Solution

Tags: sandbox-solution

How to make an ajax call in sharepoint sandbox solution.
I have created a web part. 
In that web part I have created a multiple hyperlinks and grid view so when user clicks on link gridview should be filled with the list data..